# facebook php sdk: retrieve user information

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem with retrieve basic user information. This is my code:

```
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php';
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appid', 'appsecret');

try {
    $token = 'mytoken';
    $session = new FacebookSession($token);
    $request = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
     $username = $request->getName();

    echo $username . '<br>';
} catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
    echo'Error';
    echo $e;
}
```

but no exception is throws, and nothing is printed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what could be wrong about your code, but the way i did this is, i downloaded the fb_api(version 3.2) and wrote this script:

```
<?php
require 'fb_api/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APPIDHERE',
  'secret' => 'APPSECRETHERE',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if ($user): ?>
    <p>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
        <?php echo $user_profile['name']; ?>
</p>
      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

What this code does is, it will log you in when you're not logged into facebook and will grab your basic info when you are logged in.

Comment: i don't need to log in into php page, because i invoke my script froma an android app, so i already have a valid token

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and let us know what you get

```
$my_profile_info = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/?fields=friends,id,name,birthday,email,picture,gender,location,address,email,hometown'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Comment: Can you check/debug the access token that you get. Use https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/ click on Tools and Support -> Graph Api Explorer and also whether you've public_profile, basic_info scopes